# ionic 2 implementing owl carousel 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

Hi I'm new to ionic2 and i'm trying to add owl carousel 2 from https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/
to my ionic 2 app. I have included the required css/js to the app and it loaded successfully(no console errors) but the carousel doesn't show up, Just a blank white page with no errors nothing.
I have tried the same carousel at a normal html page and it working fine.
here is my code:-

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/owl.theme.min.css">

<ion-content padding class="category">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
            <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
                <div class="item active">
                    <h4>1</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <h4>2</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <h4>3</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <h4>4</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
<script src="assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script>$(document).ready(function () {$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();});</script>
```

If the carousel not compatible with ionic2 is there any alternatives to use?

Comment: you can use [ion-slides](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/slides/Slides/)

Comment: i have tried them, they are tricky to handle i like carousel for both layout and control more.

Comment: maybe check out the [angular2 implementation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-owl-carousel)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `<script>` tag can be used in ionic 2 view, as you did.
(Moreover,Owl Carousel is made in JavaScript, but ionic 2 has typescript.)

Speaking of alternatives, you can check [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/slides/Slides/) out from ionic 2 Documentation.
(This may not be the perfect alternative, but It can be used)